# Setting a Return URL for returning after success payment

Tags: paypal

I set an Paypal button with their wizard, and set also the Return URL to
[www.mydomain.com/payment.php](http://www.mydomain.com/payment.php) and enabeled the `Return URL`.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" class="payPalBtn">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="M4VFSETEYTREQ4">  
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Now I buy an item, pay with credit card...card pass successfully but in the end I get a Paypal page like invoice with link to back to my site.

How can I make sure that after success payment the user will be redirected to my return URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the buyer pays with a credit card, there is not a way to automatically redirect the buyer back to your site.  They have to click the return link.  You could modify the text of the link to say something like, they must click this link to complete the order on your site.

The variable for the text would be "`cbt`".

Sets the text for the Return to Merchant button on the PayPal Payment Complete page. For Business accounts, the return button displays your business name in place of the word "Merchant" by default. For Donate buttons, the text reads "Return to donations coordinator" by default.

Note: The cbt variable takes effect only if the return variable is set.

Othereise, you could also set up [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to get the customers back to your site.  This is not dependent on the buyer returning to your site.  It would be sent regardless if the buyer returns to your site.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @PP_MTS_Chad, I work with almost 95% credit card payments. after payment was successful, I need to update some data in my server, what are my options doing that without asking the user to click on a link? I send kind of `uuid` number with the variable `"custom"`  and want to get it back